# A (Radon) Haar measure which is not regular

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

I've been reading about the difference between Radon and regular measures and am confused on a small point.  Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, and $\mu$ a Borel measure on $X$ (that is, a measure on the sigma algebra of Borel sets of $X$).  Suppose that $\mu$ is finite on compact sets, every Borel set can be approximated from above by open sets, and every open set can be approximated from below by compact sets.  Then $\mu$ is called a **Radon measure**.

If, moreover, every Borel set with finite measure can be approximated from below by compact sets, then $\mu$ is called a **regular measure**.

Every regular measure is of course a Radon measure, but not conversely.

The *Riesz Representation Theorem* states that given any positive linear functional $T: C_c(X,\mathbb C) \rightarrow \mathbb C$, there exists a unique regular Borel measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that

$$\int\limits_X f(x)d\mu(x) = T(f). \tag{$f \in C_c(X,\mathbb C)$}$$

Now, assume $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff topological group, with left Haar measure $\lambda$.  Then $\lambda$ is always a Radon measure, but not necessarily a regular measure.  Define a positive linear functional $T: C_c(X,\mathbb C) \rightarrow \mathbb C$ by

$$T(f) = \int\limits_X f(x)d\lambda(x).$$

By the Riesz representation theorem, there is a unique regular Borel measure $\mu$ such that

$$\int\limits_X f(x)d\mu(x) = \int\limits_X f(x)d\lambda(x). \tag{$f \in C_c(X,\mathbb C)$}$$

This implies $\mu = \lambda$, and therefore that $\lambda$ is a regular Borel measure.

This argument seems to show that every Haar measure is regular.  But I know there are Haar measures which are not regular.  What is going on here?

Comment: What nonregular Radon measures do you know?

Comment: I see where my confusion lies.  Wikipedia's definition of regular measure in the article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem is wrong; they are actually referring to Radon measures.  The Riesz representation theorem gives a bijection between positive linear functionals on $C_c(X)$ and Radon measures, not regular measures.